# C : variable global error at compilation : can not be used when making a shared project

Tags: c, variables, malloc, extern

I'm trying to make a kind of my_malloc.C but when I try to compile, this happened :

"/usr/bin/ld: block_addr.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `baseb' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value"

Well, I search a lot in google, i read this topic :

["How do I share a variable between source files in c"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how/1433387#1433387)

but this didn't solved my problem.

So, I share with you some piece of code.

First : the Makefile :

```
 CC      =       gcc -fPIC

 RM      =       rm -f

 NAME    =       libmy_malloc_$(HOSTTYPE).so

 SRCS    =       block_addr.c \
            block_ope.c \
            malloc.c \
            my_free.c

 OBJS    =       $(SRCS:.c=.o)

 all:            $(NAME)

 $(NAME):        $(OBJS)
            $(CC) -fPIC -shared -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

 clean:
            $(RM) $(OBJS)

 fclean:         clean
            $(RM) $(NAME)

 re:             fclean all

.PHONY:         all clean fclean re
```

in my .h i have it :

```
extern void             *baseb;
```

and on my malloc.c :

```
void            *baseb;

void            *malloc(size_t size)
{
 t_memblock    b;
 t_memblock    last;
 size_t        s;

  baseb = NULL;
 ..
}
```

and I use "baseb" in other function of my program.
I tried to declare "extern void *baseb;" on the begining of each files, but the compilation's error is still the same.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Do you also have `-fPIC` in the compile step?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, could you explain a little bit please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /usr/bin/ld: block_addr.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `baseb' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

This error indicates that you have not used `-fPIC` when compiling all the objects to go your shared library.

The part of a Makefile that you have shown does link, not compile, `-fPIC` has no effect there.

PS.Example:

### var.c

```
int var = 10;
```

Compile/link with:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libvar.so var.c
```

### main.c

```
extern int var;
int main() { return var; }
```

Compile/link with

```
gcc main.c -L. -lvar -o main
```

Comment: Thank to your advice, it seems to work when I tip "gcc -fPIC *.c" but impossible to make it work with the Makefile (I edited the first topic with my entire Makefile).

Comment: @JayCee, the Makefile looks OK, did you clean or otherwise make sure `block_addr.o` is not left from a previos compilation?

Comment: NEVERMIND I finally succeed to compile, thank to you !

Comment: I had to put -shared befor -fPIC to make it functionnal :)